# Boolean: Blender 2.79 - Cannot close up the back end

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

Just bought this mesh from CG Trader and would like to 3d print it. However, the back end is open. I tried to boolean Carve the Mesh, as well as other boolean combinations, but was unable o seal the mesh. 3D Manifold options did not work either. Assistance?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: at the very basic level you can just select vertices in Edit mode and press F to create a new face.

Comment: In Edit mode *Select Non Manifold* geometry and hit ALT+F to fill it with triangles